# Geo Library for Amazon DynamoDB Node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

As we know DynamonDB does not support spatial queries , We can't search by location GPS , but I found a java solution http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2013/09/new-geo-library-for-dynamodb-.html , my question is :

Are there any solution for Node.js ?

Answer (score 3):

According to amazon:

> ...we don't have short term plans to port Geo Library for other languages.

I doubt there will a node version in foreseeable future. You'll probably left with running a tomcat server just for the GEO stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Found a third party NodeJS port of the official Java library in NPM registry, named [dynamodb-geo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dynamodb-geo) with useful features.